# Sending GET Commands over SSLStream in C#?

Tags: c#, ssl, https, webclient, sslstream

I am writing an http automation framework and my problem is communicating with an authenticated http **secured** connection. After doing some research, I discovered the *SslStream* object in C# which made for easy integration with my existing client architecture. The problem is; despite being able to authenticate my connection with a given web server, any "GET [website] HTTP/1.1" commands seem to only return headers and not actual web pages.

I have a feeling that I am not forming my web requests properly, but I really don't know. I have been doing research all morning and cannot find very many resources on this particular issue. Here is a code sample from my project:

```
    private IAsyncResult Request(HttpRequestToken token, ReceiveEvent callback) 
    {
        if (token == null)
            throw new Exception("Error. No request information provided. Aborting operation.");

        //Setup the TCP Information. (_port is set to 443 for SSL purposes)
        var client = new TcpClient(token.Host, _port);

        //Get a handle to a networkstream for writing data.
        var requestStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, null);

        //Authenticate the request
        requestStream.AuthenticateAsClient(token.Host);

        //Translate the data.
        byte[] sendBuffer = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(token.ToString());

        //NOTE: The results of the above command will look like this:
        //GET [website] HTTP/1.1
        //Host: [host]
        //passive: true
        //Accepts: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
        //User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1 Fennec/2.0.1

        //Send the data.
        requestStream.Write(sendBuffer);

        //Get the string value with a function that just iterates over the stream.
        string val = readStream(requestStream);

        //Breakpoint here, this code is not complete but "functions".
        return null;
    }
```

Essentially, the results of my code will just return an "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" with some header information. No HTML or anything else is returned beyond the headers.

**As Requested, Here is some more info:**

```
    private string readStream(Stream stream)
    {
        byte[] resultBuffer = new byte[2048];
        string value = "";
        //requestStream.BeginRead(resultBuffer, 0, resultBuffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(ReadAsyncCallback), new result() { buffer = resultBuffer, stream = requestStream, handler = callback, asyncResult = null });
        do
        {
            try
            {
                int read = stream.Read(resultBuffer, 0, resultBuffer.Length);
                value += UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultBuffer, 0, read);

                if (read < resultBuffer.Length)
                    break;
            }
            catch { break; }
        } while (true);
        return value;
    }
```

For testing purposes, I am trying to access the google android developer portal (since it uses SSL). This is simply to load the login page, no information is even being transmitted at this point other than a page load request. Here is my exact request.

```
GET https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.google.com
passive: true
nui: 1
continue: https://market.android.com/publish
followup: https://market.android.com/publish
Accepts: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1 Fennec/2.0.1
```

This is the server response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000; includeSubDomains
Set-Cookie: GAPS=1:0bFTJDze2Zz8WL_x3F7-OQfOjEOycg:rG8nLpBEwdG67aU_;Path=/;Expires=Mon, 27-Jan-2014 21:31:48 GMT;Secure;HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: GALX=KaXGmr2TI-I;Path=/;Secure
Cache-control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 01-Jan-1990 00:00:00 GMT
X-Frame-Options: Deny
X-Auto-Login: realm=com.google&args=continue%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Faccounts.google.com%252FManageAccount
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sat, 28 Jan 2012 21:31:48 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
```

Thank you for taking the time to look at my question, I appreciate it! If you would like more information from me, I am happy to give it. Since I believe my mistake is probably a silly format-issue I didn't think more information would be required.

Again, thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use `HttpWebRequest` or `WebClient` which already have built-in ssl support

Comment: Thank you for the response, I appreciate it! I choose to implement my own web client for educational reasons (and I want it to be as lightweight as possible). I am willing to use the _SslStream_ object but I really wanted to understand the fundamentals behind the HTTP protocol.

Comment: It would be helpful if you code post the implementation of the `readStream` method, as well as the rest of the HTTP response (beyond the "HTTP/1.1 200 OK") that you’re receiving.

Comment: Does your code work without SSL?

Comment: @Douglas - I updated my original post to reflect the data you wanted, thanks for responding!

Comment: @arx - Yes, regular HTTP works just fine with my system.

Comment: If you read less than a full buffer you stop reading.  This just means that the data hasn't arrived yet, not that there isn't more data coming.  Only stop reading when you read zero bytes.

Comment: @arx ... well fml. That was it. Thank you SO much. gah! Can't believe I missed that!!! Thank you!!!!!!!!! How silly >_< If you respond as an answer or whatever I will mark it as the correct response.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `readStream` function terminates when it reads less than a full buffer.

However, this just means that there is no more data available now; there might be more available in the future.

Don't stop reading until `stream.Read` returns zero bytes.

Comment: Thank you so much! I would upvote but I don't have enough rep yet. Solved my problem completely!

Comment: Such a frequently misunderstood contract of the `Read` method that perhaps all designers of future frameworks should consider naming things more explicitly, like `ReadAll` and `ReadSome`, where `ReadAll` is a utility method implemented in terms of `ReadSome`.

Answer (score 3):

When reading an HTTP message:

- If you're in the header, you should keep reading until the end of the header (that is, when it encounters two consecutive `CRLF` sequences, i.e. an empty line). You should then start reading the body.
- When you're in the message body:

  - If there is a `Content-Length` header, you should keep reading until you've read the number of bytes expected from this header.
  - If you're using [Chunked Transfer Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) (which is your case here: `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`), you should look for the `0` termination character (but you'll also have to analyse all the chunks and glue them together, since you don't want to stop when the actual content contains a `0`).

There is in general no way to distinguish a TCP connection closed abruptly from one that just isn't sending anything. Whether you read 0 bytes from `stream.Read` or not, the only way to know that you have all the message you should have received is to do this analysis. (You may find that dealing with chunked transfer encoding may make your own library a bit less lightweight than you'd like.)

Comment: Sorry for the late response! I haven't checked back in a few days. Just wanted to say thank you for the information =) I, more or less, finished my library already and - indeed - I had some trouble with knowing when I was finished. For simplicity, I set a rather small timeout and then just look for /r/n/r/n which seems to be the standard for termination, but not always. It works well enough but proper support for chunked transfer encoding is something I should definitely work on...